# Apache Airflow without celery or kubernetes

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, celery, airflow

Is there any way to run workflows by not using celery or kubernetes. Doc specifies only two ways to run it in multi-cluster mode. Can't I just have another multiple EC2 instances to run my workers for computations. (Without using celery or kubernetes).

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a number of EC2 instances. How would you manage them from Airflow? How would you distribute the load among those EC2 instances? Celery or Kubernetes take care exactly of these tasks.

If, for some reason, you cannot use Celery or Kubernetes, you can install Airflow on a single instance and scale up its resources as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accomplish what you want is to write your own Executor (EC2Executor?) that fulfils your requirements.